# support multiple kafka topics as inputs in telegraf

Tags: apache-kafka, monitoring, telegraf

i have telegraf config which has inputs as below which is supporting 1 kafka topic as input is it possible/recommended to add multiple topics in inputs

```
current >>
[[inputs.kafka_consumer]]
   brokers = ["<kafka endpoint>"]
   topics = ["topic1"]
   max_message_len = 100000
   data_format = "json"

expected >>

[[inputs.kafka_consumer]]
   brokers = ["<kafka endpoint>"]
   topics = ["topic1", "topic2"]
   max_message_len = 100000
   data_format = "json"
```

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's [possible](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/plugins/inputs/kafka_consumer/kafka_consumer.go#L125) to consume from a few topics.
A recommendation will depend on your use case, for example, if you want to use a different [consumer group](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/plugins/inputs/kafka_consumer/kafka_consumer.go#L70) for each one of them.